# How to specify output type in MATLAB when using calllib

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Can I specify the output type when using `calllib`? My problem is MATLAB is automatically converting my output to a `double` even though I need an `int64` and am losing needed precision.

**Example**

I have the following function defined in `my_header.h`

```
__int64 my_function(int arg1);
```

I can call the function like this:

```
loadlibrary('my_library', 'my_header.h')
output = calllib('my_library', 'my_function', arg1)
```

But then `output` is a `double` and I am losing needed precision.

**What I tried**

```
output = int64(calllib('my_library', 'my_function', arg1))
```

as well as

```
output = zeros(1, 'int64')
output(1) = calllib('my_library', 'my_function', arg1)
```

but these just convert my `double` to `int64` after it has already lost the needed precision.

Comment: This problem will become even more involved with the new HDF5 library version 1.10.x, where handles of the type hid_t have become a 64 bit signed integer. Future Mablab version will not be able to use this HDF5 version until calllib is adapted accordingly to return 64 bit integers to full precision.